# PostgreSQL group by newly defined column with ambiguous name

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create a view with some column with the same name as the original table. The query looks like this.

```
SELECT
  mmo.model_id AS model_id,
  mmo.location_id AS location_id,
  COALESCE(
    sp.replacement,
    mmo.part_number) AS part_number,
  SUM(mmo.attr) AS attr
FROM model mmo
  LEFT JOIN part sp
    ON mmo.part_number = sp.part_number
GROUP BY
  mmo.location_id,
  part_number
```

However, the part_number column in `GROUP BY` is ambiguous.

If I assign a different column name such as `part_id`, it works just fine.

```
SELECT
  mmo.model_id AS model_id,
  mmo.location_id AS location_id,
  COALESCE(
    sp.replacement,
    mmo.part_number) AS part_id,
  SUM(mmo.attr) AS attr
FROM model mmo
  LEFT JOIN part sp
    ON mmo.part_number = sp.part_number
GROUP BY
  mmo.location_id,
  part_id
```

However, I'm trying to use this query to define a view with the same structure as the original model table, so replace the column name is not ideal.

I can make a sub query to achieve this like

```
SELECT
  model_id,
  location_id,
  part_id AS part_number,
  attr
FROM (
  SELECT
    mmo.model_id AS model_id,
    mmo.location_id AS location_id,
    COALESCE(
      sp.replacement,
      mmo.part_number) AS part_id,
    SUM(mmo.attr) AS attr
  FROM model mmo
    LEFT JOIN part sp
      ON mmo.part_number = sp.part_number
  GROUP BY
    mmo.location_id,
    part_id
)
```

but it is not elegant. I wonder if there is a better solution that I can refer to the column just defined by `COALESCE`. Maybe something like:

```
SELECT
  mmo.model_id AS model_id,
  mmo.location_id AS location_id,
  COALESCE(
    sp.replacement,
    mmo.part_number) AS part_number,
  SUM(mmo.attr) AS attr
FROM model mmo
  LEFT JOIN part sp
    ON mmo.part_number = sp.part_number
GROUP BY
  mmo.location_id,
  this.part_number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `GROUP BY` clause you can identify a column by its number:

```
SELECT
  mmo.model_id AS model_id,
  mmo.location_id AS location_id,
  COALESCE(
    sp.replacement,
    mmo.part_number) AS part_number,
  SUM(mmo.attr) AS attr
FROM model mmo
  LEFT JOIN part sp
    ON mmo.part_number = sp.part_number
GROUP BY
  2, 3
```

See the first paragraph in [the relevant section of the documentation.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)

Comment: Thanks. This is probably good enough for me now, but I'm curious if there is a way to make it more readable besides adding comments following 3.

Comment: I do not think so, but it is sufficiently legible for a non-novice Postgres user.

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to column from the select list by its position in the list:

```
GROUP BY mmo.location_id, 3
```

You could argue this is even less elegant than using a subquery to relabel things (or just repeating the coalesce call in the GROUP BY) but it is certainly shorter.

Comment: Try:  GROUP BY
        mmo.location_id,
        mmo.part_number